# Cannot translate Swift 2.2 currying to future Swift format

Tags: swift, currying

I have the following curried function and I received an Xcode warning that *Curried function syntax will be removed in a future version of Swift; use a single parameter list*, but the suggested fix-it didn't work (it simply combined the parameters into one function call). I am trying to convert to the new format, but I don't understand how it works. The `beginFetchWithCompletionHandler` function below expects `handleDownload` to have the parameter signature of `(data : NSData?, error : NSError?)`.

```
fetcher.beginFetchWithCompletionHandler(handleDownload)
```

I want to also pass in an integer, as follows:

```
fetcher.beginFetchWithCompletionHandler(handleDownload(0))
```

The following curried function works perfectly (but gives the warning):

```
func handleDownload(iCount : Int)(data : NSData?, error : NSError?) -> Void {
    print(iCount)
    print(data!.length)
}
```

Here is what I've tried, but I get the error, "Expression resolves to an unused function":

```
func handleDownload2(iCount:Int) -> (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void {
    return { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in {
            // received image
            print(iCount)
            print(data!.length)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner curly braces are wrong, it should be:

```
func handleDownload2(iCount:Int) -> (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void {
    return { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // received image
        print(iCount)
        print(data!.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Swift Evolution proposal [SE-0002 - Removing currying func declaration syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md#removing-currying-func-declaration-syntax) that was accepted states:

> We remove support for multiple argument patterns in `func` declarations, reducing the grammar for `func-signature` to allow only one `argument` clause. For migration purposes, existing code that uses currying declaration syntax can be transformed to explicitly return a closure instead:

```
  // Before:
  func curried(x: Int)(y: String) -> Float {
    return Float(x) + Float(y)!
  }

  // After:
  func curried(x: Int) -> (String) -> Float {
    return {(y: String) -> Float in
      return Float(x) + Float(y)!
    }
  }
```

---

Thus, the answer given by *Martin R* in order to solve your code is correct:

```
func handleDownload2(iCount: Int) -> (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void {
    return { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // received image
        print(iCount)
        print(data!.length)
    }
}
```

---

Note, however, that you can be more concise:

```
func handleDownload2(iCount: Int) -> (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void {
    return { (data, error) in
        // received image
        print(iCount)
        print(data!.length)
    }
}
```

Here, the type of `data` and `error` is implicitly given by the return type of your `handleDownload2` function: `(NSData?, NSError?) -> Void`.

---

Although I would not recommend it for readability matters, your code can be even more concise by using [shorthand argument names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

```
func handleDownload2(iCount: Int) -> (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void {
    return {
        // received image
        print(iCount)
        print($0!.length)
    }
}
```

---

Furthermore, I sometime try to be explicit when I use closures as it helps me set quickly the correct return type for them:

```
func handleDownload2(iCount: Int) -> (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void {
    let innerBlock: (NSData?, NSError?) -> Void = { (data, error) in
        // received image
        print(iCount)
        print(data!.length)
    }
    return innerBlock
}
```